# Prove that if $f:U\to V$ is holomorphic and injective, then $f'(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in U$.

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from Stein's Complex Analysis page 207 on the chapter about conformal equivalence.

Proof:

> We argue by contradiction and supposed that $f'(z_0)=0$ for some
> $z_0\in U$. Then
>
> $f(z)-f(z_0)=a(z-z_0)^k+G(z)$ for all $z$ near $z_0$,
>
> with $a\neq 0,k\geq 2$ and $G$ vanishing to order $k+1$ at $z_0$. For
> sufficiently small $w$, we write
>
> $f(z)-f(z_0)-w=F(z)+G(z)$, where $F(z)=a(z-z_0)^k-w$.
>
> Since $|G(z)|<|F(z)|$ on a small circle centered at $z_0$, and $F$ has
> at least two zeros inside that circle, Rouche's theorem implies that
> $f(z)-f(z_0)-w$ has at least two zeros there. Since $f'(z)\neq 0$ for
> all $z\neq z_0$ but sufficiently close to $z_0$ it follows that the
> roots of $f(z)-f(z_0)-w$ are distinct, hence $f$ is not injective, a
> contradiction.

I saw many similar questions on MSE, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer unfortunately.
I understand we can do the taylor expansion $f$ about $z_0$ and simplify as the above equation. But I don't know why we need sufficiently small $w$. I know Rouche's theorem and that it is used here, but I don't really understand why the above inequality holds and all roots are distinct. I think pictorial explanation will help, and I can't seem to think of any proper one. Can you please explain what's going on in the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I don't know why we need sufficiently small $w$.

The larger $w$ is, the larger the circle needs to be to ensure that $F$ has roots inside of it. If $G$ grows quickly enough, this may push the circle into regions where $|F| \ge |G|$ becomes false. We know exactly how $F$ behaves, but we have very little information about the behavior of $G$.

For simplicity, I'll assume that $z_0 = 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. The general case follows by translation.

There are two things that must be satified. For the $w$ we use, there has to be an $r$ such that

1. on the circle of radius $r, |G| \le |F|$, and
2. The magnitude $\left|\frac wa\right|^{1/k}$ of the zeros of $F$ must be less than $r$.

Now $G(z) = z^{k+1}g(z)$ for some holomorphic $g(z)$. Because $g$ is continuous at $z = 0$, it is bounded on a neighborhood. So there is some $M > 0$ and some $R > 0$ such that for all $z \le R, |g(z)| < M$, and therefore $|G(z)| \le |z|^{k+1}M$. To assure both conditions are met, we need to choose $r$ such that
$$r <\min\left\{\frac{|a|}M, R\right\}$$ Then choose a $w$ such that
$$|w| < \min\left\{|a|r^k, r^k(|a| - rM)\right\}$$

Since $|w| < |a|r^k$, we have $\left|\frac wa\right|^{1/k} < r$, so the roots of $F$ are inside the circle, and since $|w| < r^k|a| - r^{k+1}M$ we have for $|z| = r < R$,

$$|G(z)| \le Mr^{k+1} < |a|r^k - |w| = |a||z^k| - |w| \le |az^k - w| = |F(z)|$$

Since $k \ge 2$, $F$ has at least two roots, which are all within the circle. By Rouche's theorem, so does $f(z) - w = F(z) + G(z)$. Which means there are at least two $z$ for which $f(z) = w$, though this counts multiplicities.

But this works for any $0 < |w| < r$ and as $|w| \to 0$, so do the roots of $f(z) = w$. Since $f'(0) \ne 0$, and $f'$ is continuous, there is some neighborhood of $0$ in which $f' \ne 0$ anywhere. For small enough $w$, the roots $z$ must be in the neighborhood, and since $f'(z) \ne 0$, it cannot be a multiple root. Hence the roots of $f(z) = w$ must be distinct.

Comment: Thank you. How did you get the choice of $r$ and $w$ if I may ask?

Comment: if $w = 0$ and $|G|$ is as big as my earlier inequality allows, then $|G| < |F|$ on $z = r$  becomes $r^{k+1}M < r^k|a|$. The fact that the inequality is strict allows some room for $w$ not to be $0$. Since the $G$ inequality requires $|z| < R$ to hold, we also need $r < R$. Once $r$ is chosen, with $w \ne 0$, setting $|G| < |F|$ and applying the triangle inequality on $|F|$ puts a limit on the size of $|w|$. The other limit on $|w|$ is exactly condition (2).

Comment: I couldn't really understand at the time and I'm looking back at it. Could you explain why you said that $f'$ was continuous at the end?

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic, which means it is infinitely differentiable at all points in its domain. So $f'$ is differentiable itself, and therefore must also be continuous. Admittedly, the small snippet you gave did not directly include this information, but it is pretty much a given for anything in complex analysis, and several of the steps shown imply that it is the case.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense because $C^1$ implies $C^{\infty}$

Comment: While going through your argument I find two minor flaws in the last paragraph of your answer. First of all $f(z) = w$ has a zero in $|z| \lt r$ provided $|w| \lt r^k(|a| - rM)$ (the bound for $w$'s should not be $r$). Secondly we are assuming at the outset that $f'(0) = 0$ (OP's $z_0$ is replaced by $0$) and try to arrive at a contradiction. So your argument fails here. Rather what you can argue is that since $f$ is holomorphic so is $f'$ and hence the roots of $f'$ are isolated by identity theorem. So there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that $f'$ has no zero inside $0 \lt |z| \lt \delta.$

Comment: Another thing I want to point out is that you have taken $r \lt \min \left \{\frac {|a|} {M}, R \right \}$ but $\frac {|a|} {M}$ is not of any use here I guess and hence it might be dropped. Also $r^k(|a| - rM) \leq r^k |a|.$ So the moment you ensure that $|w| \lt r^k (|a| - rM)$ then $|w| \lt r^k |a|$ is already ensured. So you don't need to consider that into account as well. Otherwise the proof is very nice.